# Does Installing a previous version of DirectX overwrite the latest version of DirectX Installed?

Tags: directx

This is regarding about the DirectX that some applications - in particular games use.

If I am installing a program and it offers to install a previous version of direct x - say Directx9c, does it overwrite your current version (example:  Directx 12?)

Or is it like similar to the case of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables where you need certain versions of these in order to run various programs?

Also - if you want to install two different programs that are both bundled with Directx9 and are offered during installation, you should not need to install Directx9 anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All DirectX versions work together with each other, older version would not overwrite
a newer version, same as newer version wouldn't overwrite an older version.

In fact, most game installations also install their own version of DirectX,
to be sure of what is installed. Although DirectX is backwards-compatible
(within reason), the game needs to ensure that all the required
modules are installed.

What I usually do when a game or a program offers to install DirectX,
is to decline if my installed version is the same or higher.
If problems occur, I then install the game's DirectX version to fix it.